# HTML/CSS 960 layout, 24 column grid system

Tags: html, css

I was having a chat with a designer about how to make my life easier to build site templates.  They showed me a page layout overlaid with 24 columns and I can see that everything fits very nicely within the the 24 columns but I fail to see how this can help me build templates more efficiently and accurately.

My preference is for the designer to provide a page design overlaid with dimensions, much like architectural blueprints.  This is how I've always done this, but I am open to faster and better methods.

Any opinions/ideas on this?

Steve

Answer (score 0):

It lets you rough out designs in PS and write the initial layout code much faster, though it does have limitations/annoyances.

If you want a bordered box with padding (etc) within those columns you'll have to nest a tag inside a "grid_x" div, otherwise it'll send stuff off the grid.

Comment: do you know of any places with good read ups? I've done some research and found some fairly decent pages... but I'm curious to find out whether developers have found using the grid layout easier to implement especially when you're rolling out sites every other week..

Answer (score 0):

give a try to fluid24.org maybe can give you some ideas